# How to find corresponding wavenumber of FFT in Python

Tags: python, scipy, fft, frequency

I have some data which I have performed an FFT on using `scipy.fft.rfft` and I found the corresponding frequencies using `scipy.fft.rfftfreqs`

Is there a way to find the corresponding wavenumbers or wavelengths rather than frequencies? Since I don't know what the velocity is I am not sure how to convert frequencies into wavelength and ultimately wavenumber.

I would like to compare my data with theoretical data which is in terms of wavenumber. My data is high speed imaging taken at 27000 frames per second for 4.3 seconds. I perform image analysis to track a certain position over time. This gives me a data set of pixel values which vary over time which I performed the FFT on.

Comment: You say you don't know the velocity, and then later you give a velocity: 27000 fps for 4.3 seconds. Then you say you're tracking a certain position over time, that's literally velocity.

Comment: I'm tracking the edge of a water jet at a certain downstream location. This edge oscillates similar to a sine function. I perform the analysis on this edge location to find the dominate frequencies. I know how to find the frequency bins but I don't know how to find the wavelength bins or wavenumbers.

Comment: If you know the distance peak to peak, then you know the wavelength. If you then know the frequency and the wavelength, you can calculate the wave speed. If you know the wave speed you can calculate the wave number.